# Is a relative path in a CSS file relative to the CSS file?

Tags: css, path

When I reference an image or other file in a CSS file by a relative path, is the path relative to the CSS file or the HTML file using the CSS file?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Yes, it's relative to the `.css`

Here's an example layout:

```
Page:  page.htm ... does not matter where
CSS:   /resources/css/styles.css  
Image: /resources/images/image.jpg
```

CSS in `styles.css`:

```
div { background-image: url('../images/image.jpg');
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was really confused in the same issue, and here you just solved it in a better way.

Comment: This is indeed reasonable, because it allows referencing the _same_ `.css` file from different `.html` files (which may be located in different places) without braking paths to external objects.

Comment: Why is the brace not closed for div in styles.css ?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. It is relative to the CSS file.  I'll add that this also includes relative to the domain the CSS file is on.

So if the CSS is referenced as:

```
<link href="http://www.otherdomain.com/css/example.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and it contains:

```
div { background-image: url('/images/image.jpg');
```

The background will be:

http://www.otherdomain.com/images/image.jpg

Comment: The include from an external domain will only work in some browsers if you have set the header to allow external includes, due to the same origin policy

Answer (score 1):

To the CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's relative to the stylesheet. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) for up-to-date references; right now, the latest draft is [[css-values-4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#relative-urls)].