# Wrong relative path in css on cdn

Tags: php, html, css, cdn

I have a project on domain **example.com** all css files for this project are getting from **cdn.example.com** in this css files I used only relative paths e.g.

```
  background:url(../../images/colorbox/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
```

Due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718532/is-a-relative-path-in-a-css-file-relative-to-the-css-file) path for images should be **cdn.example.com/../../images/....**

But all images are loading from **example.com/...** not **cdn**. Is there any advices, For loading images from cdn?

Comment: don't use relative paths?

Comment: cant you use background:url(http://cdn.example.com/images/colorbox/loading.gif)?

Comment: cdn.example.com and example.com are basically two different domains, so you can't use relative paths

Comment: I Guess your css file cached

Comment: css files are loading from from cdn. 
I know that cdn.example.com and example.com are different domains, so i need images will be loading from same domain as css, so i used relative pathes. 
css file is too large to change for a absolute urls, and if cdn will change to other name

Comment: could you show the working url?

Comment: Look at the source of your CSS file and make sure that once the file is actually up on CDN, all the paths are relative. If they are NOT relative (and are set to example.com/../../images/...) you will need to log into your CDN control panel and find out what settings are causing the CSS file to be re-written. This is a feature some CDN's have so you don't have to change your CSS files by hand should you need to reference things that used to be called relatively before you went to CDN.