# External image linking

Tags: html, css, image, external

I've been attempting to link my external images in my css using background-image: Url('Background.png'); and also tried background-image: Url("Background.png"); but theyre both not working and not showing up on my webpage, however the html page is linking perfectly to my css. I am attempting to build a website locally.

Here is the current file path for my images:

Users/admin/Desktop/images

and the file path for my css:

Users/admin/Desktop/stylesheets

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a relative path in a CSS file relative to the CSS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718532/is-a-relative-path-in-a-css-file-relative-to-the-css-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by `Users/admin/Desktop/stylesheets` you mean `/Users/admin/Desktop/stylesheets/something.css` then `Url("Background.png");`* would reference `/Users/admin/Desktop/stylesheets/Background.png`.

You need to include the directory path too. `../images/Background.png`.

`*` if it works at all. I don't know if `url` is case sensitive or not.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed to know!

Answer (score 1):

you need to do `Url(../images/Background.png)`