# Relative paths in IIS 7 Web applications under a website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, routes

Is there a way to force "Paths" in a web-application under a website to resolve to actual paths under the app, rather than the site?

I'm new so I can't upload an image of what I'm talking about, but see if you can visualize my IIS setup:

```
IIS 7.0
----MAIN WEB SITE:
    ----Web App #1
    ----Web App #2
```

Each web app has its own CSS, pointing to its own images; for example in Web App #1:

```
background-image: url(images/someimage.png)
```

The problem is, since web app is installed under a main site, "images/someimage.png" resolves to the image folder of the main site, not web app #1.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this first

[There is something about "Paths" for Asp.net beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne)

UPDATE(as I'm struggling with this too):

Besides code behind MapPath("~/..."), my focus was only from HTML/CSS point of path resolution

I noticed if we talking about HTML

```
<img src="/images/x.jpg" />  this will work only from  

IIS 7.0
----MAIN WEB SITE
```

The slash "/" in front of "images" will be interpreted "go to root"

to fix for

```
IIS 7.0
----MAIN WEB SITE
    ----Web App #1
```

remove "/" so `<img src="images/x.jpg" />`  this will work for both, when hosted as site and when hosted as web application

**Now CSS is tricky** different way, I was surprised that using your example it doesn't work since there is no slash in front of the images.

consider a structure based on your expample

```
IIS 7.0
----MAIN WEB SITE:
    ----Web App #1
        ----styles
        ----images
```

Your CSS

```
background-image: url(images/someimage.png)
```

tells the browser to look for `MAIN WEB SITE/Web App #1/styles/images/someimage.png`

add "/" `background-image: url(/images/someimage.png)`

the result is `MAIN WEB SITE/images/someimage.png`

now add "../" `background-image: url(../images/someimage.png)`

the result is `MAIN WEB SITE/Web App #1/images/someimage.png`

(seems like resolved as go one level up, and then go to images)

The good part is, that once you change those prefixes to make it work as web application it seems to work even when hosted as actual web site if you need to do so

```
IIS 7.0
----MAIN WEB SITE (web app #1):
    ----styles
    ----images
```

[Sorry if this answer is not descriptive enough or messy, I will add edits when someone will propose or if I notice mistakes myself, generally firefox/chrome F12 and see paths for resources]

Comment: Relevant to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718532/is-a-relative-path-in-a-css-file-relative-to-the-css-file

Comment: This may be a workaround in some situation, but the problem is the IIS application directory not being seen as the relative root.

Comment: I have this problem too (proposed solution does not work). Does not seem that there is a solution out there. The only way I see this working is if one could use the actual URL as opposed to relative, but  you don't want to hard code it to absolute - you want the actual URL

Answer (score 1):

I add "runat="server"".
Like this:

```
<a href="~/Default.aspx" runat="server">Home</a>
```