# Relative paths in redirected CSS file

Tags: css, internet-explorer, relative-path, redirect

I'm aware of the fact that relative paths in CSS are supposed to be based on the location of the CSS file, as answered by [Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to) and [Is a relative path in a CSS file relative to the CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718532/is-a-relative-path-in-a-css-file-relative-to-the-css-file).

However, I have a content management site in which I allow overriding CSS when needed. I generate links in **head** for all the sections of a page, with a format like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/data/?s=123&get=.css">
```

If the section displayed is to use a default, static CSS file, that fact is detected by the page that serves **/content/data/**; in this case, it serves a redirect to that static file.

These static CSS files may contain relative paths to images stored in nearby folders, so when my CSS file is at **/some-folder/styles/file.css** and it contains

```
body { background-image: url(../images/section-123-bg.png); }
```

the browser looks for **/some-folder/images/section-123-bg.png**.

This does not seem to be an issue in Chrome, Safari or Firefox. IE, however, seems to look for  **/content/images/section-123-bg.png**. It appears to treat **/content/data/** as the base path of the CSS file it ends up with.

My question is:

Which source path is a browser supposed to start from when calculating relative paths in a CSS file?

- The **final** source path of the CSS file - after any redirects (like Webkit/Mozilla) or
- The **initial** source path from the href of the link element (like Internet Explorer)

Comment: I have this exact problem with IE11 right now.  A server redirect to a specific client css file.  The relative image/file paths inside the css are failing and pointing at the original url.. not the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - we're having to proxy CSS files for a legacy app, and all the relative paths are being resolved from the proxy script, not the real locations.

The easiest fix was for us to change the proxy script to output a fake CSS file that `@import`s the other CSS file instead.

```
public ActionResult Bundle(string type, string bundle)
{
    var url = Scripts.Url(bundle).ToString();
    var cssContent = string.Format("@import url('{0}');", url.Replace("'", @"\'"));

    return Content(cssContent, "text/css");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This would work as a replacement for the redirects to static files, but I'll still need to provide the dynamic CSS, which usually starts as a copy of the static version and is then modified. That variant, as a result, can have the same relative links to deal with once it gets to the browser.