# Background image is not showing in html because of path problem

Tags: html, css, image

Background image is not showing because of image path problem.

**css code**

```
background-image: url("images/menu_home_icon.png");
```

My actual image path is `EZ_MOVERS/images/menu_home_icon.png`.

But it shows `EZ_MOVERS/css/images/menu_home_icon.png` while I checking through Inspect Element.

I can't find from where `/css` comes.

Anybody help please ?

Comment: add your full code with css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the stylesheet is located in the `/css` folder. Remember that the [paths in the file are relative to the stylesheet's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718532/is-a-relative-path-in-a-css-file-relative-to-the-css-file). Based on my understanding, your directory structure looks a little like this:

```
EZ_MOVERS
 │
 ├── css
 │    └── <stylesheet>.css 
 └── images
      └── menu_home_icon.png
```

So if you want to traverse a directory up and then select the `/images` sibling folder, use `../images/menu_home_icon.png`.

Comment: it works ! It's a very silly mistake. Thanks again bro :)