# CSS does not exist?

Tags: html, css, path

I am trying to make a website, and my css seems not to exist, no error, no style, nothing.
This is what I have got:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
```

This is the path:

index.html /css --> style.css

I went to the console to search after any error, there is no error, none. In fact, I went to the sources, and it is not even there.

Please, I would like to get feedback, thank you.

Comment: Related, but maybe not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718532/is-a-relative-path-in-a-css-file-relative-to-the-css-file

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"/>
```

This should do it, or you can also replace your **type="type/css"** to **type="text/css"**

type="type/css" is not the correct link type.

Comment: Thank you, pardon my lapsus, I was tired.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful of using `/` prefix in the paths.

Also, there's no link type called `type/css`. It's `text/css`.

Both of these will work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, pardon my lapsus, I was tired.

Answer (score 0):

Set the type to `"text/css"`. Also, try not to use a `/` at the beginning of your file paths if you can.

You can use this line instead.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```